How to write camera serial number to a jpeg image using C#
I am trying to determine how to write the camera serial number to a jpeg file using C#. I had thought that it would be case of setting an appropriate EXIF header value (and maybe it is), but when I open the image using C# + System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(...), the image.PropertyIdList array does not include an EXIF id which would seem to represent the serial number.
I then opened the file in Windows File Explorer, for the jpeg file, Properties, and Details, I see no value for "Camera Serial Number".
I then used Windows File Explorer/Properties/Details to set the camera serial number to "hello". This persists. However, when I load the image using C# again, I see the same list of Ids as before - ie. I don't have a new one holding my "hello" serial number.
Is there a way, from C# code, that I can read/write the camera serial number ?
My code is very simple...
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp\example.jpeg"))
            {
                foreach (var propertyId in image.PropertyIdList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{propertyId:x}");
                    /*
10e     image description
10f     camera make
110     camera model
131     software name
8298    copyright
9003    original date
9004    digitized date
9286    comment
5091    ChrominanceTable
5090    LuminanceTable
                     */
                }
            }
        }

(the first 8 of which I wrote to the JPEG file when I saved it)

It is not Exif metadata.  This library is a wrapper for the Adobe XMP data that's being used.

This seems sketchy. What's your usage? Are you asking the user for permission to store his/her/their identifying information on each image/photo?

Not sketchy at all. I have a jpeg stream, I'm saving it as a jpeg file, I happen to know the 8 details I write as EXIF tags (see above), and I also happen to know the serial number of the camera which originally took the image/stream. As the jpeg file has the means to hold the camera serial number, I thought I might as well write it.

I believe that most people value their privacy. Adding a camera serial number to an image could be used for tracking. The increased usage of AI makes it even easier to use this information for tracking someone. If you work for the government and are interested in tracking the activity of your employees, then this may be desirable.
